# Can anyone help me understand this? JavaScript 'splice' method in prototype object

Tags: javascript

can anyone help me understand this? When i have in my prototype methods "splice" the result display in console log is "select [div#index]" without 'splice' this looks like  "select {0: div#index, length: 1}".

```
 select.prototype = {
         splice: function () {
         [].splice.apply(this, arguments);
     },
 }
```

PHOTOS:

[image: Result 1:]

[image: Result 2 without 'splice':]

Script:

```js
(function () {
    var doc = document;

    // it is for the test
    function select(sel) {

        if (sel) { this.push(query(sel)); }
        return this;
    }

    function query(selector) {
        let elems = [];
        var el = doc.querySelectorAll(selector);

            for (let i = el.length; i--; elems.unshift(el[i])) { }; 
        return elems;
    }

    select.prototype = {
        length: 0,

        push: function (elems) {
            [].push.apply(this, elems);
            return this;
        },
        // THIS METHOD
         splice: function () {
             [].splice.apply(this, arguments);
        },   

    };

    window['Q'] = function(selector) {
        return new select(selector);
    }

  console.log(window);
})();
```

`Q("#index")` to display result

Answer (score 0):

It's using the [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function on the `select` object rather than on an array. That's perfectly fine, `splice` (and several other array functions) is intentionally generic. As long as the object it sees as `this` has `length` and properties named with numeric strings, like arrays do, it'll work.

It's probably worth mentioning that the *way* it's using `splice` is over-complicated, (ever so slightly) inefficient (it creates and throws away a completely pointeless array), and doesn't return the deleted elements like `splice` on an array does (because it doesn't return the return value of `Array.prototype.splice`). This:

```
splice: function () {
     [].splice.apply(this, arguments);
},
```

should simply be:

```
splice: Array.prototype.splice
```

Example:

```js
(function () {
    var doc = document;

    // it is for the test
    function select(sel) {

        if (sel) { this.push(query(sel)); }
        return this;
    }

    function query(selector) {
        let elems = [];
        var el = doc.querySelectorAll(selector);

            for (let i = el.length; i--; elems.unshift(el[i])) { }; 
        return elems;
    }

    select.prototype = {
        length: 0,

        push: function (elems) {
            [].push.apply(this, elems);
            return this;
        },
        /*
        splice: function () {
             [].splice.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        */
        splice: Array.prototype.splice

    };

    window['Q'] = function(selector) {
        return new select(selector);
    }

})();

const x = Q(".foo");
x.splice(0, 3);
for (let n = 0; n < x.length; ++n) {
  console.log(x[n].textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">2</div>
<div class="foo">3</div>
<div class="foo">4</div>
<div class="foo">5</div>
<div class="foo">6</div>
```